# How do I evaluate this limit involving cosines with different arguments?

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry

I would like to evaluate the limit

$$
\lim_{h \to 0} \left( \frac {1 - \cos {5h}} {\cos {7h} - 1} \right)
$$

I'm having a hard time doing this, however. When you try evaluating directly, of course, it comes out in indeterminate form. I tried using the identity

$$
\lim_{h \to 0} \left( \frac {1 - \cos h} h \right) = 0
$$

by breaking the limit up into two limits, by dividing and multiplying by $h$, but that only takes me to $0 \cdot \frac 1 0$. What can I do to evaluate this?

Comment: Two applications of L'Hospital will do.

Comment: A better idea is to exploit $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1-\cos x}{x^2} = \frac{1}{2}\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{\sin(x/2)}{x/2}\right)^2 = \frac{1}{2}.$$

Comment: Then it is pretty clear that the wanted limit is $-\frac{25}{49}$.

Comment: I need to do this without using L'Hopital.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall the formula $\frac{1-\cos x}{2} = \sin^2\frac{x}{2}$ and the limit $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x} = 1$.

$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac {1 - \cos {5h}} {\cos {7h} - 1} = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac {2\sin^2 \frac{5h}{2}} {-2\sin^2 \frac{7h}{2}} = -\lim_{h \to 0} \frac {\sin^2 \frac{5h}{2}} {\sin^2 \frac{7h}{2}} = -\lim_{h \to 0} \frac {\frac{\sin^2 \frac{5h}{2}}{\left(\frac{5h}{2}\right)^2}} {\frac{\sin^2 \frac{5x}{2}}{\left(\frac{7h}{2}\right)^2}}\cdot \frac{\left(\frac{5h}{2}\right)^2}{\left(\frac{7h}{2}\right)^2} = -\frac{25}{49}$$

Answer (score 2):

**Without L'Hospital:**

By the double angle formula,
$$\frac{1-\cos5x}{\cos7x-1}=-\frac{2\sin^2\dfrac{5x}2}{2\sin^2\dfrac{7x}2}$$

which tends to $$-\left(\frac57\right)^2.$$

(You can linearize the sines as $\sin x /x$ tends to $1$.)

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Use $(1-\cos x)(1+\cos x)=\sin^2x$  and

$\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{\sin h}h=?$

Or use $\cos2y=1-2\sin^2y$

Answer (score 1):

Use L'Hospital:

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{h \to 0} \left( \frac {1 - \cos {5h}} {\cos {7h} - 1} \right) &=
\lim_{h \to 0} \left( -\frac {5\sin(5h)} {7\sin (7h)} \right) \\
  &=\lim_{h \to 0} \left(- \frac {5^2\cos(5h)} {7^2\cos (7h)}\right) \\
&= -\dfrac{5^2}{7^2}\\
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks for the help! I need to do this without using calc, though; this is before we've gotten to derivatives.

Comment: Hm its fine! There are many answers which don't use l'hospital! I just prefer it over trigonometric substitutions when it works, because, you know, why reinvent the wheel! :)

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{h \to 0} \left( \frac {1 - \cos {5h}} {\cos {7h} - 1} \right) = \lim_{h \to 0} \left( \frac{(1-\cos^25h) \cdot (\cos7h + 1)}{-(1-\cos^27h) \cdot (1 +\cos5h)} \right) = \lim_{h \to 0} \left( \frac{-\sin5h }{\sin7h}\cdot \frac{\sin5h }{\sin7h} \cdot \frac{\cos7h+1}{\cos 5h + 1} \right) = \frac{5}{7} \cdot \frac{5}{7} \cdot \frac{1}{1} = \frac{-25}{49}$$